# Iterating through vector for search function

Tags: c++

I have a `vector<int>` which I need to search for a given value `val` and then return the index `i` of the first occurrence of that value. If the vector is empty, it should return the constant `EMPTY_VEC` This is what I have so far.

```
const int EMPTY_VEC = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
size_t find(const std::vector<int>& v, int val)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if(v[i] == val) { 
            return i;
            break;

        } else if(v.size() == 0) {
            return EMPTY_VEC;
        }
    }}
```

When I call this function, it returns 0 everytime.

Could it have something to do with the way my vector is defined?

```
uint32_t seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    // uint32_t is a type that is guaranteed to be 32 bits wide (unlike int or unsigned int)
    // seed is the pseudorandom value returned from the system clock object (like time(0))

    std::minstd_rand gen(seed);
    // gen is the object responsible for creating the random numbers

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,BIGGEST_RANDOM);
    // choose random ints between 0 and BIGGEST_INT

    // OK, stop ignoring now
    std::vector<int> data {};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        data.push_back(dist(gen)); // dist(gen) is the random int
    }`

 std::cout << find(data, 8) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Show the definition of `EMPTY_VEC`.

Comment: Added definition

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Does your vector contain the value you're searching for? What your function is supposed to do when there is no occurences?

Comment: I'm using CoCalc and it's not showing any errors. The vector has 100 elements and I'm running the function many times, so it is unlikely that there are no occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to compiler warnings, you are missing a return at the end of the function. Note that your `if(v.size() == 0)` condition is **inside the loop** and it's not very useful in any case. Your function should've been something like this:

```
const int EMPTY_VEC = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
size_t find(const std::vector<int>& v, int val)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (v[i] == val) { 
            return i;
        }
    }
    return EMPTY_VEC;
}
```

It would be better, however, to use [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead:

```
auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), val);
if (it != v.end()) {
    // do something if value is found
}
```

Comment: I need it to find and return only the first occurrence. If the vector is empty (in my case it is not), return EMPTY_VEC (but this part is not important). How do I go about making it such that when I call `find(vector, 3);` it returns the first occurrence of 3 in the vector?

Comment: @DasarGashi, the code above does exactly what you are asking. It also returns `EMPTY_VEC` if the value not found at all (including the case when the vector is empty), so `EMPTY_VEC` isn't really and appropriate name for this value.

Comment: In CoCalc it is simply returning 0. `EMPTY_VEC` was given by my professor. I'll tell him that :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function has one error that leads to undefined behavior and two constructs that show lack of clarity.

```
size_t find(const std::vector<int>& v, int val)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
      if(v[i] == val) { 
         return i;

         // Lack of clarity.
         // The function will never hit this line.
         // The return statement above will ensure that.
         break;
      }

      // Lack of clarity.
      // This else block will never be executed.
      // You will enter the for loop only when v is not empty.
      // Hence, the conditional will always evaluate to false.
      else if(v.size() == 0) {
         return EMPTY_VEC;
      }
   }

   // Error.
   // Missing return statement. This causes undefined behavior.
}
```

If you notice that the function returns 0 every time, there are two things that I can think of that can explain the behavior.

1. 8 is the first item in `v`.
2. 8 is never found in `v`. The function happens to return 0 when it hits the end of the function even though there is no `return` statement. Please note that this is simply a sign of undefined behavior. Don't depend on that value.

I think it will be better to change the return type to `int`. You can return a valid index if the item is found and -1 if the item is not found.  Returning `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` when the input vector is empty does not sound right.

```
int find(const std::vector<int>& v, int val)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (v[i] == val) { 
            return i;
        }
    }

    // Item not found. Return -1.
    return -1;
}
```

With that change, there is no need to treat empty vectors any differently than non-empty vectors.

Comment: Now it is returning just `-1`